# Tkinter - Getting values from spinbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently having trouble getting the correct value from the spinbox widget. I do not know what is wrong. I have searched for solutions and have come empty. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

#create Tk window
root = Tk()

#set name of window
root.title('Testing Values')

#initalise values from user (spinbox values)
item_1 = IntVar()
a = item_1.get()

def print_item_values():
    global a
    print a


#item 1 spinbox
item_1 = Spinbox(root, from_= 0, to = 10, width = 5)
item_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

#print values
value_button = Button(root, text = 'Print values', width = 10, command = print_item_values)
value_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, `a` is never updated. Instead, to get the spinbox value, just use its `.get()` method:

```
item_1 = Spinbox(root, from_= 0, to = 10, width = 5)
item_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

def print_item_values():
    print item_1.get()
```

[Tkinter Spinbox Documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can make following changes in your code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Testing Values')

item_1 = IntVar()

def print_item_values():
    a = item_1.get()
    print(a)

item_1 = Spinbox(root, from_= 0, to = 10, width = 5)
item_1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

value_button = Button(root, text = 'Print values', width = 10, command = 
print_item_values)
value_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```